# How to change Screen Time and Privacy restrictions settings programatically from inside an app or from an external MDM?

Tags: ios, swift, parent-child, ios12

IOS 12 introduced some basic screen time settings.

Is there any way to view or change these settings programatically from inside an app or from an external MDM?

Specifically, I would like to be able to change the time limits, the downtime schedule, and/or the list of allowed apps. Ideally from the parent device but from the child device or from an MDM would be acceptable too.
I want a solution like an existing application did.(https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/id981066103 Parental Control - Screen Time)

Answer (score 0):

I'm really interested in this as well, and can share my findings with you here:

- There is no possible way to use the screen time / API at the time of writing. Since apps use .entitlements now, private APIs are out of the question as well.
- Apple is *most likely* thinking about releasing a screen time API, since the feature is added in the iOS Simulator.
- Apple is rejecting and removing screen time apps for no apparent reason right now.

There is one solution for now though: use MDM. The mobile device management system does not allow you to change the screen time settings on the device, but you *do* have control over what apps are allowed to be opened. Bind this to some date/time logic and you have a simplified version of the screen time app. The same function can also be used to track the time an app has been opened.

The app you mentioned uses the above MDM solution as well. (Actually, all apps do)